# EF: on delete no action on nullable foreign keys not working

Tags: entity-framework, mariadb, sql-delete

Following scenario:

I've got an entity 'Material' with a required foreign key to an entity 'MaterialType'. I set up the relationship with ON DELETE NO ACTION.
If I would try to delete a MaterialType which is used in a Material, mariaDB would reject the statement stating that this MaterialType is still in use and because of that cannot be deleted. That works and is the expected behaviour. So far so good.
The entity Material also has an optional foreign key to an entitiy 'Additive'. This relationship also has ON DELETE NO ACTION. If I would try to delete an Additive this time, the mariaDB database rejects the statement as expected. But the EF would set all references to Additives in Materials to NULL and eventually delete the Additive.
I disabled cascade delete on both foreign keys. What am I missing here? Or do I really have to check all nullable relations myself before deleting an entity?

This is the Material:

```
Public partial class Material 
       Inherits Entity

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Additive that enhances this material.
        ''' </summary>
        <System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Verstärkung")> _
        Public Overridable Property AdditiveId() As Global.System.Nullable(Of Long)
            Get
                Return _AdditiveId
            End Get
            Set
                If (Object.Equals(_AdditiveId, value) = false) Then
                  Me.OnAdditiveIdChanging(value)
                  OnPropertyChanging("AdditiveId")
                  _AdditiveId = value
                  Me.OnAdditiveIdChanged()
                  OnPropertyChanged("AdditiveId")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _AdditiveId As Global.System.Nullable(Of Long)

        ''' <summary>
        ''' The material type of this material, e.g. PC, PET, etc.
        ''' </summary>
        <System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required()> _
        <System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Materialtyp")> _
        Public Overridable Property MaterialTypeId() As Long
            Get
                Return _MaterialTypeId
            End Get
            Set
                If (Object.Equals(_MaterialTypeId, value) = false) Then
                  Me.OnMaterialTypeIdChanging(value)
                  OnPropertyChanging("MaterialTypeId")
                  _MaterialTypeId = value
                  Me.OnMaterialTypeIdChanged()
                  OnPropertyChanged("MaterialTypeId")
                End If
            End Set
        End Property
        Private _MaterialTypeId As Long

        ''' <summary>
        ''' The material type of this material.
        ''' </summary>
        <System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Materialtyp")> _
        Public Overridable Property MaterialType() As MaterialType

        ''' <summary>
        ''' The additive that enhances this material, if any.
        ''' </summary>
        <System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Verstärkung")> _
        Public Overridable Property Additive() As Additive
End Class
```

This is my model:

```
        Partial Public Class Data
           Inherits DbContext

           Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
              ' Material

               modelBuilder.Entity(Of Material)() _
                   .Map(Sub(tpc)
                         tpc.MapInheritedProperties()
                         tpc.ToTable("Materials")
                     End Sub)
               ' Properties:
               modelBuilder.Entity(Of Material)() _
                   .Property(Function(p) p.AdditiveContent) _
                       .HasColumnType("double")
               modelBuilder.Entity(Of Material)() _
                .Property(Function(p) p.AdditiveId) _
                    .HasColumnType("bigint")
               modelBuilder.Entity(Of Material)() _
                   .Property(Function(p) p.ManufacturerId) _
                    .IsRequired() _
                    .HasColumnType("bigint")
            modelBuilder.Entity(Of Material)() _
                .Property(Function(p) p.MaterialTypeId) _
                    .IsRequired() _
                    .HasColumnType("bigint")
            ' Associations:
            modelBuilder.Entity(Of Material)() _
                .HasMany(Function(p) p.Tasks) _
                    .WithRequired(Function(c) c.Material) _
                .HasForeignKey(Function(p) p.MaterialId) _
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(False)

            ' Additive

            modelBuilder.Entity(Of Additive)() _
                .Map(Sub(tpc)
                         tpc.MapInheritedProperties()
                         tpc.ToTable("Additives")
                     End Sub)
            ' Association:
            modelBuilder.Entity(Of Additive)() _
                .HasMany(Function(p) p.Materials) _
                    .WithOptional(Function(c) c.Additive) _
                .HasForeignKey(Function(p) p.AdditiveId) _
                    .WillCascadeOnDelete(False)
   End Sub
End Class
```

And this is how I delete:

```
 If RadMessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} wirklich löschen?", msg), "Löschen", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        For Each row In e.Rows
            Data.Entry(row.DataBoundItem).State = EntityState.Deleted
        Next
        Try
            Data.SaveChanges()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Util.printError(ex)
            e.Cancel = True
            reload()
        End Try
    End If
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is one of the EF6 pitfalls. You are doing nothing wrong, but there is no way to let EF do what you need. EF Core provides more options in that regard, but currently has other drawbacks.